# PHP REGEX - text to array by preg_split at line break

Tags: php, regex, preg-split, line-breaks

**EDITED:**

need help on split Array

array example:

```
 array (

           [0] =>
            :some normal text
            :some long text here, and so on... sometimes 
            i'm breaking down and...
            :some normal text
            :some normal text
        )
```

ok, now by using

```
preg_split( '#\n(?!s)#' ,  $text );
```

i get

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => some normal text
            [1] => some long text here, and so on... sometimes
            [2] => some normal text
            [3] => some normal text
        )
```

I want get this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => some normal text
            [1] => some long text here, and so on... sometimes i'm breaking down and...
            [2] => some normal text
            [3] => some normal text
        )
```

what **Regex** can get the entire line and also split at line break!?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you want to split on newlines at all but rather `TEXT:`

Comment: ok, just for make things clear, i need a REGEX that donn't cut off the line but keep it fully! all other method seen here are not for me! ;-)

Comment: forget the TEXT# , just consider my Regex, it is working well, but it split also the long string, i need it to keep the long lines fully!!!

Comment: ok, i have updated once more time my question, the delimiter is a **colon** **:** what is the regex i'm finding!? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example that works, even if you have a colon character embedded inside the string (but not at start of the line):

```
$input = ":some normal text
:some long text here, and so on... sometimes
i'm breaking: down and...
:some normal text
:some normal text";

$array = preg_split('/$\R?^:/m', $input);
print_r($array);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some normal text
    [1] => some long text here, and so on... sometimes
           i'm breaking: down and...
    [2] => some normal text
    [3] => some normal text
)
```

Comment: i don't need to split **TEXT:** this is just an example for delimit each line!!!!!!

Comment: Ok, so, which character exactly delimits the lines?

Comment: thank's Milan! i think the hardest thing, this time, for me, is to make my question clear! doh! %-) but finally we got it so thank's again! +1 and check!

Answer (score 21):

"line break" is ill-defined. Windows uses CR+LF (\r\n), Linux LF (\n), OSX CR (\r) only.

There is a little-known special character \R in preg_* regular exceptions that matches all three:

```
preg_match('/^\R$/', "\r\n"); // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

[`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) reads a file into an array.

Comment: Thanks posting something useful, non-intuitive, and answers the needs of many similar questions. Even if it ignores the stated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the array on the : character..

```
print_r(preg_split('/:/', $input));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
```

Comment: Does not handle any case except `\n`