# Use line-break as separator for an array input?

Tags: php

I've never actually used arrays before, as I've never had to so far (a simple variable has been enough for me), however now I've created a form with a text-area that is meant to POST multiple urls through to my PHP script.

What I want to do is use a line-break in the visitors input to act as a separator for an array input.

For example, the visitor inputs 90 lines of text (all url's), the array breaks each one into a list of 90, and creates an array value for each one.

Any info, advice or comments would be greatly appreciated :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% percent sure what line breaks are used, e.g.:

Windows uses `\r\n`
Linux uses `\n`
(old) Macs used `\r`

However if you know this you can simply do:

```
$urls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);
```

**EDIT**

Actually after testing using regex IS faster than first doing a `str_replace()` and explode.

Comment: Thanks :). Exactly what I was looking for, I've seen the explode function used before, but never had an idea of what it actually did).

Comment: Use str_replace and your explode will work every time: `$urls = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $_POST['urls']);`

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php and as delimiter use new line sign

or see [PHP REGEX - text to array by preg_split at line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716324/php-regex-text-to-array-by-preg-split-at-line-break)

be careful about using just `\r` or `\n` because every operating system has "new line" defined another way
see answer by `Tgr` on SO question [PHP REGEX - text to array by preg_split at line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716324/php-regex-text-to-array-by-preg-split-at-line-break#answer-2716436)

Comment: Regex aren't really needed here I think. When regex aren't really needed don't use them

Comment: regex is needed because new line is somethimes another than just `\n` so it is better to use preg_replace and `\R` switch to handle them all

Comment: it is? Let me run a test. 1 sec. If you're right you're right :)

Comment: I have a linux based server, so "\n" acts as a line break, unless you're saying that the visitors "OS" itself determines the line break?

Comment: @Fireworksable: what if you need to change your hosting for some reason. Even if you don't coding should always be done by writing code that will 'always' work

Answer (score -1):

Use explode

```
$array=explode("\n",$_POST['textarea']);
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. So, when I call $array[0], $array[1] etc, I take it that gives the value of line?

Comment: $array[0] is first line $array[1] is second one,etc